# Node js s3fs Image uploading to aws amazon s3 server and setting ContentType

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

Below is my node javascript code for image uploading to Amazon S3 using the `s3fs` library. Images are getting uploaded correctly, but when I try to view that image in a browser it's giving the error  mentioned below.

I checked the Content-Type, and it's getting saved as `octet-stream` by default. If I manually set it to `image/jpeg` then that image is viewable in browser. Can anyone tell how I can set the Content-Type while uploading only or just after uploading is finished?

I have tried to set Content-Type but its not working for `S3fs` image uploading.

Error Code:-

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
</Error>
```

My Actual Code:-

```
    var AWS= require('aws-sdk');

    var fs = require('fs');

    var S3FS = require('s3fs');

    var s3fsImpl = new S3FS('bbqmobileimages/images/banners',{
        accessKeyId:'A********A',
        secretAccessKey:'****************'
    });

    var multiparty = require('connect-multiparty'),
        multipartyMiddleware = multiparty();

    router.use(multipartyMiddleware);

        router.post('/api/v1/backoffice/upload/image',function(req,res){

            console.log(JSON.stringify(req.files));
            var file = req.files;
            console.log("file",JSON.stringify(file))
            console.log("original name:- "+file.fileUpload.originalFilename);
            console.log("Path:- ",file.fileUpload.path);
            var stream = fs.createReadStream(file.fileUpload.path);
            return s3fsImpl.writeFile(file.fileUpload.originalFilename, stream).then(function(){
                fs.unlink(file.fileUpload.path, function(err){
                    console.error(err);
                })
                console.log("Sucessfully uploaded to Amazon S3 server");
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
s3fsImpl.writeFile(file.fileUpload.originalFilename, stream, {"ContentType":"image/jpg"})
```

found here: https://github.com/RiptideElements/s3fs/issues/45